# Application to manage software updates on multiple desktops?

Tags: updates, landscape

I have a small home network of 5 Ubuntu Maverick desktops and 1 laptop.  Is there any application that would allow me to manage all software updates from a single location?  I guess much like Landscape, but for a home network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [cfengine](http://www.cfengine.org/) or [puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) is what you want.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer for the time being.  I checked out puppet and it looks like it might do what I want, however, I was looking for more of an out of the box solution.  Thanks for the pointer though.

Answer (score 0):

canonical's landscape which is a paid service can manage computers from any location if they are connected to internet. Here's a good info regarding landscape.
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/tag/landscape/

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of Landscape, as I mentioned.  I'd rather a non-paid solution for a small home network.